# Where can i find tutoral for Designing building in 3dsmax

Tags: architecture, 3dsmax

I have searched various tutorials for 3ds max. They only show simple house apartment and that too not compelete.

Is there any online company which have tutorial set for complete building design from start to finih so that i can get idea how to model complete bulding

Comment: What kind of building would you like to design? Skyscraper? Monument?

Comment: basically building with rooms and interior like hotels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this tutorial for basic building :

http://www.free3dtutorials.com/modeling-and-texturing-a-building-in-3dsmax-2009.php

For a more complex building, you have this one in 2 parts :

http://www.free3dtutorials.com/modeling-a-high-definition-building-part-1.php

http://www.free3dtutorials.com/modeling-a-high-definition-building-part-2.php

As for the interior you can find many tutorial that explain how to design them :

http://www.cgarchitect.com/resources/tutorials/smoke3d/tutorial13.asp

http://cg.tutsplus.com/tutorials/autodesk-3d-studio-max/modelling-and-rendering-an-interior-scene-in-3ds-max/

Answer (score 1):

This is a great Tut for you, from floor plan to complete walls and furnishings:

http://youtu.be/9prgBEXRX6Y

Have fun

Comment: Hello, and welcome to GD.SE. We ask that users explicitly disclose their involvement when linking to things they control or have some stake in.